# add_custom_command doesn't rebuild when dependencies change

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I run a python script over each of my source files in order to generte additional code. The generated code can then be included in the source file and its content be used.

```
#include <Main.cpp.generated.hpp>
```

In order to make it work with CMake, I've added this python script as a custom cmake, because it seems to be the common way to make it work.

My CMake script looks like this (ignore the hardcoded paths, it's a proof of concept).

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
project(test)

add_executable(target Main.cpp test.h for_each.hpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/Main.cpp.generated.hpp)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT gen/Main.cpp.generated.hpp
    COMMAND python D:/Projects/clang-plugins/test-gen/test-gen.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/Main.cpp.generated.hpp
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp)

target_compile_features(target PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(target PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen)
```

Everytime I modify my Main.cpp file, the generated file is rebuilt. Which is good. However, if a file included by Main.cpp changes, the generated file is not rebuilt. Which is a problem because then the generated code can be outdated. I can fix it by adding those headers into the DEPENDS arg, but I don't want to do this my hand.

I don't want to trigger my custom command everytime the file Main.cpp changes, but everytime the file Main.cpp is rebuilt.

Comment: maybe you could add a dependency on the object file compiled from main.cpp?

Comment: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2015-November/062085.html

Comment: You're looking for `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` (if you only use a Makefile generator) or `DEPFILE`.